# Number of spins until a bicycle stops

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

After taking off the feet from the pedal, the front wheel of a bicycle spins 500 times during the first minute.

In the next minute, it spins $\dfrac{3}{5}$ of the number it did in the last minute and so on. This process is supposed to be infinite.

I have to evaluate the number of spins until the bicycle stops. Clearly, it's a geometric series with $a_{1}=500$ and $q=\dfrac{3}{5}$.

I know I have to evaluate the infinit sum
$$S_{\infty}=\frac{a_{1}}{1-q}$$
to answer the question. But why can I assume this value is when the bicycle, in fact, stops?

Comment: you're right, it never quite stops (theoretically)

Comment: It stops because $(\frac{3}{5})^n$ gets smaller as $n$ gets larger. At infinity, the wheel will have spun a finite number of times but the angular speed will go to zero.

Comment: This is a very poorly worded problem.  The intended answer, which refers to the limit of a geometric sum, would take an infinite amount of time to reach.  You are supposed to ignore that, and compute the number of wheel spins, given an infinite amount of time, which is a ludicrous assumption.  In the presentation of math problems, brevity is often the soul of poorly worded problems.

Comment: In retrospect, the problem composer has *boxed themself into a corner*.  They are trying to disguise the geometric sum by presenting it in a real world setting.  Even ignoring the requirement of an infinite amount of time, this approach still won't work.  The (strictly increasing) partial sums never actually reach the limit of the geometric sequence.  Instead, these partial sums merely *approach it*.  Related : [zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).